# Missing firmware/nouveau/nvc1_fuc084

Tags: firmware, nouveau

When I try to do a graphic boot, I get this error "direct firmware load for nouveau/nvc1_fuc084 failed with error -2".
This file "nvc1_fuc084" is missing in /lib/firmware/nouveau .

Where can I download this "nvc1_fuc084" file ?

Comment: Did you try installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers? If so, then run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the correct proprietary Nvidia drivers and then reboot when it's done.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help troubleshoot your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I download this "nvc1_fuc084" file ?

The solution proposed by mchid uses Nvidia's proprietary closed-source driver.
If you prefer to use the free Nouveau driver, which to my knowledge you cannot download anywhere as a ready-to-use DEB package, follow the instructions below, which refer to the following source:

https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/VideoAcceleration.html#firmware

For explanation: The Ubuntu package nouveau-firmware unfortunately does not contain the firmware you are looking for! Note that if a package called nouveau-firmware is installed, then you most likely do not have the correct firmware (it contains ctxprogs for very old versions of nouveau). If this is the case, uninstall it now. The following steps would otherwise mix with the drivers in the /var/firmware/nouveau directory, resulting in a mess of old and new files!

```
$ sudo apt remove nouveau-firmware
```

Now work through the following commands step by step:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/nouveau
$ cd /tmp/nouveau
$ wget https://raw.github.com/envytools/firmware/master/extract_firmware.py
$ wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/325.15/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-325.15.run
$ sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-325.15.run --extract-only
$ python2 extract_firmware.py
```

The drivers are now in the /tmp/nouveau directory and must still be copied to the correct place. Since the target directory belongs to root, the following commands must be executed with sudo:

```
$ sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/nouveau
$ sudo cp -d nv* vuc-* /lib/firmware/nouveau/
```

Besides many new firmware files you will now find the required nvc1_fuc084 in the directory /var/firmware/nouveau.

```
$ ls -l /lib/firmware/nouveau/ | grep nvc1_fuc084
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Okt 13 22:58 nvc1_fuc084 -> nvc0_bsp
```

nvc1_fuc084 exists as a symbolic link to nvc0_bsp.